# Rails 3.2.1 logging in Passenger, Thin, or Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger, thin, unicorn

I've tried those 3 hosting approaches for my Rails app, and no matter what I do, I can't get consistant logging when I run in the production environment.

For my tests, I created a blank app and tried to access the root directory.  I would then add a users scaffold and rake the database.

If I turn RAILS_ENV to development, the log/devlopment.log works just fine, logging everything that I would expect.

When I turn RAILS_ENV to production, the log/production.log logs in a strange manner.  In Passenger, I get the first routing error. Then nothing.  When I restarted apache or nginx, I would get all the routing errors that I had caused since the first (logged) one, then the log would fail to write anything new until I restarted the underlying server.  apache2/error.log would get logged to if I had a configuration issue.  Then it only logged cache misses

With Thin and Unicorn, I only get errors about the static assets (I did not precompile the assets).  Once I precompiled the assets, no more log messages appeared.

On all 3 setups, I would get precompilation messages (when I ran assets:precompile) in production.log (indicating that Rails could at least write to the log).

Does anyone have a Rails 3.2.1 app that is running on one of the deployment gems (Passenger, Thin, or Unicorn), that is logging correctly in production mode? I've spent 5 days working on this.  I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its a reported issue in Rails 3.2.x.  A fix has been submitted and will hopefully be released with Rails 3.2.2.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277